# What are the widths of Shimano 8, 9, and 10 speed cassettes?

Tags: road-bike, chain, cassette, sprocket

I was hoping that someone could provide me with the precise Shimano road-bike 8, 9, and 10 speed sizes for the following:

1. Cassette Spacer Width
2. Cog/Tooth Width
3. Maximum Chain Width

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I think these may be what you're looking for. FYI, a lot of this information is available with a little searching. Depending on what exactly you are looking for, you might want to look up a document for a specific cassette as the numbers might be slightly different.

**Spacer widths (From Shimano tech docs)**

- 8  Spd: 3.00mm
- 9  Spd: 2.56mm
- 10 Spd: 2.35mm (1.0mm for lower spacer)

**Cog/Tooth Width (From Sheldon Brown)**

- 8  Spd: 1.8mm
- 9  Spd: 1.78mm
- 10 Spd: 1.6mm

**Chain widths (From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicycle_chain#Width))***

- 8 speed - 7.1mm (all brands)
- 9 speed - 6.6 to 6.8mm (all brands)
- 10 speed - 6.2mm (Shimano, Campagnolo)
- 10 speed(Narrow, Direction) - 5.88mm (Shimano CN-5700,CN-6700,CN-7900)

*These chain widths are the standard widths, which I assume are recommended. I wouldn't go wider, but a narrower chain will probably work as some chains are cross-compatible.

Comment: +1 for being generous enough to provide an answer despite the fact that op could have easily have found the answer through Google.

Comment: @PeteH Google won't have it nicely in one place like this. Well, it probably does now, if it points to this question!

Comment: @Kaz People have maintained these lists on web pages for years!

Comment: @PeteH, By the way, this morning I used a caliper gauge to measure, down to the micron, a KMC Z51 (which was labelled as a 6-7-8 speed), as well as a SRAM PC-850 (labeled as just 8 speed on the packaging). The both measured quite exactly 7.65 mm, not 7.1,  at the widest girth. I wonder whose 8 speed chains actually measure 7.1.

Comment: you have too much time :-)

Comment: @Kaz Seriously, I see KMZ say their chain is suitable for Shimano and Campagnolo drivetrains, which are slightly different dimensions. Possibly KMZ have come up with some kind of halfway house which is close to each but exact to neither? SRAM may be the same, although they sit far more firmly in the Shimano camp where road bikes are concerned.

Comment: Pitty the OP didn't ask for overall cassette widths too.