# Halfords just replaced my chainset and it is a 10 speed one, but my cassette is 8 speed. Am I ok?

Tags: gears

Last week my chainset was replaced (in warranty) and I just found out that the chainset is 10 speed (FSA Vero) but my rear cassette (+Claris gears and shifters) is 8 speed.

I want to know if I will be fine. The bike is Carerra TDF Limited Edition 2012 model.

Comment: no you're not. Regarding the width of the chain, 8 speed is different to 9-speed is different to 10-speed is different to 11-speed. People will say you can get away with mismatches, but coming straight out of a shop, you shouldn't have to "get away" with anything. There has to be a question on here that covers this, U'll have a quick look.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What Are the Widths of Shimano 8, 9, and 10 Speed Cassettes?](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/17064/what-are-the-widths-of-shimano-8-9-and-10-speed-cassettes). Not an exact dup, but will give an idea of how the widths vary with number of gears.

Comment: This is in regards to a crankset, not a cassette, so it isn't a duplicate.

Comment: Sorry for being offline. Some good replies. I am yet to test it after the gears were adjusted (due to work). I think I will just have to visit a different/better halfords store and complain about my experience and ask them to fit me an 8sp chainset.

Answer (score 3):

In my experience this is a non-issue. The only difference between 8,9,10 speed chains is the exterior width not the interior. That matters a lot on the rear cassette, but not much if at all on the front. From this [article](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/17064/what-are-the-widths-of-shimano-8-9-and-10-speed-cassettes) the difference in the exterior width of 8spd chain vs 10 spd is 0.9mm. On the front that just doesn't make any signficant difference.

If you had a triple crankset and really short chainstays, you might run into some issues, but with a double and your bike, it should just work.

I'd say take the bike for a test ride and if you're happy with the way the front derailler shifts and it is capable of cross-chaining then I wouldn't worry about it. At this point insisting on an 8spd replacement will only get you a very low quality crankset.

Comment: As it looks in the article you linked to, the cog/tooth width differ between 8-10 by 0.2mm. Doesn't it mean, that interior of chain is also narrower?

Comment: No, they are all 3/32 inch width chains. You can run a 10 speed chain on ancient cogs if you want to. Think about how wide 0.2 mm actually is, that's two human hairs.

Answer (score 2):

The distinction of speeds especially in the front is primarily for marketing. You're fine with this '10 speed crankset'.

Comment: Nope, width at the front is important because an 8 speed front d will shift much further out than a 10 speed front d. Restricting the H screw will help but a struggle to get perfect and keep in trim. They could have also put a new 9 or 10 speed chain on because some 8 speed chains would be too wide on a 10 speed spaced crank.

Comment: Look at the numbers, at best the difference between chainrings on 8 and 10 spd is 0.45 mm. That's well beyond the installation tolerance.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly, the different designations are there to encourage whole component group sales. As a general rule (not an absolute one), you can mix and match derailleurs and chainrings with other parts, but only with a one speed difference and with the other parts being the lesser speed.

In other words, 8 speed chain, shifter, and cassette (these three must match except for 6-8 speeds) are ok with 9 speed elsewhere, but not 10.

Realize that there is usually a difference in chain width, so there are potential exceptions to this rule.

Comment: No. Shifter must match rear derailleur number of cogs. Exception is 6, 7, 8 where the cable moves the same amount. 8, 9, 10, 11 are differ each from other.

Comment: that's what i meant. edited to reflect as such.

Comment: the derailleurs & chainrings don't need to match the shifter, cassette or chain. is that clear?